# PHP Includes in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

Ive been learning PHP and tried to get into RoR and the two are always compared.My question is, is there a PHP include equivalent for Ruby on Rails. To me the ability to include PHP files is it's most valuable feature.

Comment: *(tipp)* http://railsforphp.com/

Comment: PHP include is what makes development in PHP really messy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP is a programming language while Ruby on Rails is a framework therefore you're comparing two completely different things.

Assuming that you use include in PHP to build a page from many nested templates/scripts then partials would be the way to go in Rails, e.g.:

```
<%= render :partial => 'sidebar' %>
```

Ruby itself has also `require` which behaves similar to `include` or `require` in PHP but it doesn't work for views in Rails.

Comment: Here the direct link to the documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Answer (score 2):

I believe the closest equivalent would be utilizing :partial

Answer (score 0):

For code rather than markup, Ruby's notion of modules can also work the way includes work.